# Terminology: "sufficiently large absolute constant"

Tags: pr.probability, terminology, random-matrices, definitions

I'm currently reading the paper *["Random matrices: The distribution of the smallest singular values" by '"Terence Tao and Van Vu"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00039-010-0057-8)* and have run into some terminology which I don't quite (rigorously) understand.

In Theorem 1.3, the authors state that $\mathbb{E}[|\xi|^{C_0}]<\infty$ for some *sufficiently large absolute constant* $C_0>0$.   What does "sufficiently large absolute constant" mean?  I googled it but I couldn't find a definition.

Comment: So it holds for any $\xi$ random variables in $L^2$?

Comment: "Absolute constant" usually means it does not depend on any of the fixed data.

Comment: Any random variable $\xi$ ? No.  Any random variable $\xi$ as specified in Theorem 1.3.  If $\xi \in L^2$, then it hods for $C_0=2$ by definition of $L^2$.  Presumably the random variables  in Theorem 1.3 need not be in $L^2$, so he has to use a larger constant $C_0$.  Perhaps they state it that way because they do not actually compute the constant $C_0$ that works, they only prove that one exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Absolute constant" means that it does not depend on anything. For example, $3, 10^{12},\pi$ and Feigenbaum number are absolute constants. They are  real numbers. "Sufficiently large" means that
the authors did not care or could not compute or estimate it.